# Spring Rest Controller find by id/ids methods

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have the following method in my Spring RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DecisionResponse findById(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long decisionId) {
....
}
```

Right now I need to add the possibility to find a set of DecisionResponse  by `{decisionIds}`.. something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionIds}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<DecisionResponse> findByIds(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Set<Long> decisionIds) {
....
}
```

The following two methods don't work together.

What is a correct way of implementing this functionality? Should I leave only one method(second) that waits for `{decisionIds}` and returns a collection even when I need only 1 `Decision` object? Is there another proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a single endpoint for both sending a single long value as well as for the array of long values:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionIds}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<DecisionResponse> findByIds(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Set<Long> decisionIds) {
          System.out.println(decisionIds);
}
```

And call this endpoint by sending path variable like this:

> http://localhost:8080/11,12,113,14

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that **you can't have 2 different methods on the same endpoint**.

In other words, you can't have these two methods at the same time :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DecisionResponse findById(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long decisionId) {
....
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionIds}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<DecisionResponse> findByIds(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Set<Long> decisionIds) {
....
}
```

Because

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionIds}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

And

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Are the same endpoint.

So when you have HTTP request GET on `http://<host>/19`, you can't determine which method you want to use.

**Solution**

Rename your endpoints more clearly to avoid conflicts

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/decision/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

And

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/decisions/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I hope this will help you.